# How to get readable summary text description of a mailbox processing rule

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to fetch a user's mailbox processing rules.

```
upn = 'joe@company.com'
headers = {'Authorization': bearer_token}
url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{upn}/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.json()
```

It works, however the rules are returned in a raw json format that's kind of ugly to look at.

```
{
  "id": "AgAAA9FcN-I=",
  "displayName": "For all messages from Mail Delivery Subsystem",
  "sequence": 1,
  "isEnabled": true,
  "hasError": false,
  "isReadOnly": false,
  "conditions": {
    "subjectContains": [
      "some random subject"
    ]
  },
  "actions": {
    "delete": true,
    "stopProcessingRules": true
  }
}
```

Looking at the same mailbox from the office365 website, the mailbox rule is displayed in a nice readable format:

> For all messages from Mail Delivery Subsystem
>
> If the message includes specific words in the subject "some random subject", delete the message and stop processing more rules on this message.

Is there a way to fetch this rule summary text from the MS Graph API?

Comment: No that's something the client eg (Outlook or OWA) does not the backend (Exchange) so if it's something you need then you will need to come up with your own implementation.

Comment: @GlenScales Thanks for the comment.  Is there a way to access the client implementation?  Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It not documented anywhere that I know off,  Get-InboxRule in the EXO cmdlets has an implementation in the description property.